# Align <div>'s in <td> horizontally

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to align three `div`'s horizontally in a `td`.

I want also change `div` of `A` and `B` in the picture below:

[image]

It is just important that `A` goes left side of the `SecondOne` and `B` on the right of it. I used `span` as well but it didn't work.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reshadgp/w5zu09ny/)

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="width: 55px; background: yellow; margin-left: 50px;">
        FirstOne
      </div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div style="width: 11px; background: red; margin-left: 50px">
        A
      </div>
      <div style="width: 75px; background: green; margin-left: 50px;">
        SecondOne
      </div>
      <div style="width: 11px; background: red; margin-left: 50px">
        B
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="width: 65px; background: blue; margin-left: 50px;">
        ThirdOne
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `div` to `display:inline:block`

Don't use inline styles.

```css
.table-divs {
  font-size: 0;
  /*fix inline-block gap*/
  border: 1px dashed red
}
.table-divs div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px
  /* set font-size again */
}
.table-divs td:nth-of-type(2) {
  padding: 0 50px
}
.first {
  width: 55px;
  background: yellow;
}
.second {
  width: 75px;
  background: green;
}
.third {
  width: 65px;
  background: blue;
}
.a,
.b {
  width: 11px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-divs">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="first">
        FirstOne
      </div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div class="a">
        A
      </div>
      <div class="second">
        SecondOne
      </div>
      <div class="b">
        B
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="third">
        ThirdOne
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
<hr />
<div class="a">
  A
</div>
<div class="second">
  SecondOne
</div>
<div class="b">
  B
</div>

<div class="third">
  ThirdOne
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but the one of Pietro Lerro is more like what I wanted.

Comment: Thanks again. That's great, But I have other div's in my page which should not be inline-block. So I marked his answer as correct. But your's also is really helpful

Comment: @reshad then just use inheritance and specificity just to target those divs. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the style part of your middle 3 divs:

```
float: left;
```

So it becomes:

```
<table>
  <tr>
<td>
  <div style="width: 55px; background: yellow; margin-left: 50px;">
    FirstOne
  </div>
</td>

<td>
  <div style="width: 11px; background: red; margin-left: 50px; float: left;">
    A
  </div>
  <div style="width: 75px; background: green; margin-left: 50px;float: left;">
    SecondOne
  </div>
  <div style="width: 11px; background: red; margin-left: 50px;float: left;">
    B
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div style="width: 65px; background: blue; margin-left: 50px;">
    ThirdOne
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You  can use float property
```

below is the working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/w5zu09ny/1/

Answer (score 1):

user "float: left" to put div on left and remove "margin-left" for secondOne and B

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="width: 55px; background: yellow; margin-left: 50px;">
        FirstOne
      </div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div style="width: 11px; background: red; margin-left: 50px;float: left;">
        A
      </div>
      <div style="width: 75px; background: green; float: left;">
        SecondOne
      </div>
      <div style="width: 11px; background: red;float: left;">
        B
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="width: 65px; background: blue; margin-left: 50px;">
        ThirdOne
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td>
      <div style="width: 11px;background: red;margin-left: 50px;float: left;">
        A
      </div>
      <div style="width: 75px;background: green;float: left;">
        SecondOne
      </div>
      <div style="width: 11px;background: red;float: left;">
        B
      </div>
    </td>
```

Comment: It's exactly what I needed, because I wanted A and B attached to the center box. Thanks !!! in 10 minutes I will mark as correct answer

Comment: Awesome! Glad it helped! :)